# Setting a background color to my UITableViewCell won't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color

I have a view with a table view, programmatically created (no XIB associated). I want some of the cells to have a light gray background color.
So I tried this :

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.f) green:(230/255.f) blue:(230/255.f) alpha:1.0];
```

But here is the result (the problem is of course that the background of the cell should be entirely gray):

[image]

I also tried this, with the same result as previous:

```
UIView *cell_view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[cell_view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.f) green:(230/255.f) blue:(230/255.f) alpha:1.0]];
[cell setBackgroundView:cell_view];
```

Nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try with this cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set tableviews background color to clear color.

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do following:

1. Set tableview background color to clear color.
2. set cell.backgroundview to nil.
3. set cell.backgroundcolor to gray color.

Answer (score 0):

Dont give background color. Instead create a view with required color. and set to backgroundView.

Comment: Already tried it, it didn't work (see updated post). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.f) green:(230/255.f) blue:(230/255.f) alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Also, set the textLabel background color to transparent

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work too. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//set this in viewDidLoad method
yourTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//set this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView
cell.backgroundview = nil;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me.

please try this code:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIColor *CellColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.f) green:(230/255.f) blue:(230/255.f) alpha:1.0];
cell.backgroundColor = CellColor;
```

}